# Why it works only partially this condition?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this site:

http://www.moment-of-style.com/

On the first page you will find a large image slider having first and then small images.

This slider is made by me using JQuery and has the following condition.

```
        if(jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").first()){
            jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
        }
```

If the first element, then the picture will be taken great ... I wish the same for these two elements.

I tried this code.

```
    if(jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").first() ||jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").nth-child(2)){
        jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
    }
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Do you know what is the problem? Can you help me fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#slider #left-slide img').hide();
jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").first().show();

if (jQuery('#slider').hasClass('ru-slide')){
if(jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").first()){
    jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
}
}

var index = 0;
var len = jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").length
var count = len -1;

function bannerRotator() {
    jQuery('#slider #left-slide img').delay(4300).eq(index).fadeOut("slow",function() { 
        if (index === count){
            index = -1;
        }

        jQuery('#slider #left-slide img').eq(index + 1).fadeIn("slow",function() {
            index++;
            bannerRotator();
        });

        if (jQuery('#slider').hasClass('ru-slide')){
            if(index == -1){
                jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
            } else {
                jQuery('#left-slide').removeClass('full-banner');
            }
        } else {}
    });
}
bannerRotator();
```

});

Comment: You need to check `.length` on the result of these selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your checking nth-child is wrong

```
if(jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").nth-child(2)){
```

it returns undefined

`:nth-child` is a psudeo-class selector. so we check like below

```
if(jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").first().length > 0 || jQuery("#slider #left-slide img:nth-child(2)").length > 0){
        jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
 }
```

or check with `eq()`

```
if(jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").eq(0).length > 0 || jQuery("#slider #left-slide img").eq(1).length > 0){
        jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
 }
```

Comment: If you want I can put all the code for this script and HTML

Comment: show me the code I will try or fiddle be apprieaciated

Comment: I could not put code in fiddle but I made an update to my post code